# VB6 Time from the Internet

Tags: vb6

I am trying to build a program that tells the exact time from the internet and not from the computer itself. I am using Visual Basic 6.

Is there a way for me to get this, and if yes, what will it return if it failed to connect to the internet?

Comment: What have you already tried ?

Comment: I've searched the net for answers, unfortunately I can't find one. I've made a bunch of personal applications using vb6, but never tried making something like connecting to the internet, and I don't have a history about it. I've also scan a reference but it seems none of it talks about the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link shows how to do it in VBScript. Should work equally well in VB6.

http://www.visualbasicscript.com/internet-time-update-m57973.aspx

Comment: thanks, a little edit and it works perfectly for my plans.